# using awk with subprocess Popen

Tags: python, awk

```
import subprocess
gpus_raw=subprocess.Popen(['sinfo -pmain -Ogres:100,nodelist -N -h -r -tidle,mix,alloc| 
                           grep -v drng | awk -F " " '{print $1,$2}''],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True).communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')
```

I use subprocess to generate a file with two columns after a grep and awk to remove the third colunn
but I get an error

File "/usr/bin/savail", line 10
`gpus_raw = subprocess.Popen(['sinfo -pmain -Ogres:100,nodelist -N -h -r -tidle,mix,alloc|grep -v drng | awk -F " " '{print $1,$2}''], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 shell=True).communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')`
                                                                                                                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Should `'{print $1,$2}''` be `"{print $1,$2}"'`?  It looks like the strings aren't being terminated correctly.

Comment: the grep output and three columns i would print $1 and $2   awk  '{print $1,$2}'

Comment: quotes aren't matching up? missing a comma between parameters?

Comment: yes , but i use the shell=True  it's not necessary the comma between parameters?

Comment: @ahmedmamlouk I'm not sure what you're trying to say. :-(  I was just trying to point out that your use of single quotes and double quotes appears to be out-of-balance.  The string starts with a single quote (`'`) and then you have a single quote just before `{print $1,$2}`, which terminates the string and leaves `{print $1,$2}"...` to be interpreted as Python code, and is clearly not syntactically correct--hence the error message you are seeing.  I think if you fix that, your problem goes away.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @ jszakmeister thank you for your help yes i saw the error is i change my code into made.

Comment: As @jszakmeister said `{print $1,$2}` should be wrapped by single quotes, but **escaped** ones: `awk -F" " \'{print $1,$2}\''`

Comment: yes thank you @Jdamian it's working now ,I added the \ to escape